# div align issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code:

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:250px;float:left">
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;float:right">
        <div>2222</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what i am getting:
[image]

How can i make that div not get out from the content place holder ( it has no fixed width, if i put any dat in there it just stretches down, it seem to have a problem with that float:left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [clear/contain your floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

The best simple way to do this is to add `overflow: hidden` to your outer `<div>`:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:250px;float:left">
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;float:right">
        <div>2222</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another common fix is to use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Either method is fine, but `overflow: hidden` almost always works (..except when you don't want the overflow to be hidden) and is easier.

Comment: You might also find [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/n645G/) visual demonstration useful.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the first div isn't that wide
OR
give the first div a `display: inline-block;`
OR
set a `<div class="clear">` div at the end with a linked style `.clear { clear: both;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:250px;float:left">
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;float:right">
        <div>2222</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:250px;float:left">
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
        <div>1111</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;float:right">
        <div>2222</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a clear div below your floating divs:

**Struction** : CLEARER being the clear div [see HTML]

-Container Start-

-floating items-

-CLEARER-

-Container End-

**HTML**

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing a div is not a very nice way of forcing the container div to grow.

the way i always do it is like this:

```
<div style="width:400px; min-height=:150px; overflow: hidden;"

    <div style="width:200px; height:300px; float:left;">content goes here....</div>

    <div style="width:200px; height:300px; float:left;">content 2 goes here....</div>

</div>
```

more easy like this you wont get.
when this is not working because for some reason (like i had) content goes out of the div with minus margins try using another div  behind it.
it will keep the code nice and clean.